# Prove that $f(x) = \frac{x}{2} + c$ if $|f(x+y)-f(x-y)-y|\le y^2\ \forall \ x,y \in \mathbb{R}$

Tags: calculus, limits, limits-without-lhopital

Problem Statement: Let $f:\mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ be a function such that $\forall \ x,y \in \mathbb{R}$,
$$|f(x+y)-f(x-y)-y|\le y^2$$
Prove that $f(x) = \frac{x}{2} + c$ for some $c\in \mathbb{R}$

My try:
$$|f(x+y)-f(x-y)-y|\le y^2 \\ \implies \frac{y-y^2}{2y}\le \frac{f(x+y)-f(x-y)}{2y} \le \frac{y+y^2}{2y}\ \ \text{when}\ y \ne 0$$ 
Now, taking the limit as $y \to 0$ in the above inequality and using the Squeeze theorem we have
$$\lim_{y\to 0}{\frac{f(x+y)-f(x-y)}{2y}} = \frac{1}{2}\ \ \forall x \in \mathbb{R}\ \ \ (*)$$
Now, if it is given that $f$ is differentiable on $\mathbb{R}$, then we have $f'(x)=\frac{1}{2}\  \forall \ x \in \mathbb{R} $ and hence $f(x) = \frac{x}{2} + c$ for some $c \in \mathbb{R}$
But since the problem does not explicitly state that $f$ is differentiable on $\mathbb{R}$, I am not sure on how to proceed after step $(*)$.

Thanks for any answers!!

Comment: What you have done is essentially sufficient. Take $t, h \in \mathbb R$ arbitrary with $h\neq 0$ and choose $x,y$ so that $x+y= t+h$ and $x-y = t$. This is the same as $x =t+h/2$ and $y = h/2$. Then letting $h\to 0$ your reasoning shows that $f’(t)= 1/2$ for all $t\in \mathbb R$.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Put $x = a+h/2$, $y = h/2$ to have $|f(a+h) - f(a) - h/2|< h^2/4$, or $$\left| \frac{f(a+h)-f(a)}{h} - \frac12\right| < \frac{h}{4}$$. What can you say about the diffentiablity?